# For a random variable $X$, how can we characterize the events that unambigously describe possible properties of the outcome of $X$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, stochastic-filtering

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space, $(\hat{\Omega}, \hat{\mathcal{A}})$ be a measurable space and $X : \Omega \rightarrow \hat{\Omega}$ be a random variable.

We say that an event $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is a *possible property* of $X$ if and only if, for all $w \in \Omega$, knowing the value of $X(w)$ is enough information to unambigously decide whether $w \in A$ or $w \in A^{c}$ ( = whether $A$ happened or did not happen). In other words, $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is a possible property of $X$ if and only if there is a set $E \subseteq \hat{\Omega}$ such that $A = X^{-1}(E)$. If $A$ is a possible property of $X$, one can always choose $E \subseteq X(\Omega)$.

We denote the set of all possible properties of $X$ as $\mathcal{B}(X)$. I am trying to characterize $\mathcal{B}(X)$  and understand its relation to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$.

The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that $X$ is measurable and is given by $$ \sigma(X) := X^{-1}(\hat{\mathcal{A}}) =\{X^{-1}(\hat{A}) \ \vert \ \hat{A} \in \hat{\mathcal{A}}  \}. $$

Clearly, all events in $\sigma(X)$ are possible properties of $X$ and it holds that $\sigma(X) \subseteq \mathcal{B}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{A} $. Note, that $\sigma(X)$ depends on $X$ and $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$. I wonder what necessary and sufficient conditions on $X$ and $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$ are such that $$ \sigma(X) = \mathcal{B}(X).  $$

It is not hard to see that $$ \mathcal{B}(X) =  X^{-1}(\mathcal{P}(\hat{\Omega})) \cap \mathcal{A}, $$ where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set. In particular, this implies that $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is always a $\sigma$-algebra. If we write $$ \sigma(X) =  X^{-1}(\hat{\mathcal{A}}) \cap \mathcal{A}  ,$$ it becomes clear that $\hat{\mathcal{A}} = \mathcal{P}(\hat{\Omega})$ is a sufficient condition for $ \sigma(X) = \mathcal{B}(X)$. However, I do not think this condition is necessary and it is rarely fulfilled in practical applications.

What are conditions on $X$ and $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$ for $ \sigma(X) = \mathcal{B}(X)$ that are both necessary and sufficient?

I'm happy to hear as many thoughts as possible on this!

Kind regards,
Joker

Comment: Is it not just that you want every possible output X(w) be measurable in the range (i.e. in $\tilde{\mathbb{A}}$? Since then, I think you will have your desired condition, and if not, then you can "hide information" in your non-measurable sets in your range. Not sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a necessary and sufficient condition. After it's proof, there are some results and examples that came to my mind, which led me to the answer I give here.

[NOTATION: I changed $\mathcal B(X)$ to $\mathfrak B(X)$ in order to avoid confusion with 'borelian sets of X'—a notion that makes sense whenever a topology is explicitly defined or assumed by default for $X$; although $X$ is a function, it is itself a set—like everything in ZFC—and then it always admits the notion of a topology.)

> A necessary and sufficient condition for $\sigma(X)=\mathfrak B(X)$ is
>   $$\forall A \in \mathcal A, \quad X^{-1}\big(X(A)\big)\in \mathcal A \implies  X(A) \in \hat{\mathcal A}.$$

*Proof*: To see that it is a necessary condition, let's assume (on the contrary), that there is a set $A_0\in \mathcal A$ such that
$$X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)\in \mathcal A \quad \wedge \quad X(A_0) \notin \hat{\mathcal A}.$$

Then, while $X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)$ is a set in $\mathcal A$ of the form $X^{-1}(\hat A)$ with $\hat A \subset \hat\Omega$, and so $$X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big) \in \mathfrak B(X),$$
this is not a set in $\sigma(X)$, since is not of the form $X^{-1}(\hat A)$ **and** with $\hat A\in \hat{\mathcal A}$. This comes from the fact that
$$X^{-1}(\hat A)=X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)$$
implies
$$\hat A=X\big(X^{-1}(\hat A)\big)=X\Big(X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)\Big)=X(A_0)$$
and so, by hypothesis $\hat A=X(A_0)\notin \hat{\mathcal A}$. Since $X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)$ cannot belong to $\sigma(X)$, it turns out that $\sigma(X)\subsetneq\mathfrak B(X)$. This shows the condition is necessary.

Now, lets assume the condition holds.

Let $A_0 \in \mathfrak B(X)$, which means
$$A_0 \in \mathcal A \quad \wedge \quad \exists \hat A_0 \subseteq\hat \Omega \colon \; A_0=X^{-1}(\hat A_0)$$
and the last equality implies that $X(A_0)=\hat A_0$.

We want to see that there is some $\hat A_1 \in \hat{\mathcal A}$ such that $A_0=X^{-1}(\hat A_1)$. But 
$$A_0=X^{-1}(\hat A_0)=X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)\in \mathcal A$$
(because $A_0 \in \mathcal A$). But the condition (assumed by hypothesis), implies that $X(A_0)\in \hat{\mathcal A}$.

So that $A_0=X^{-1}(\hat A)$ with $\hat A \in \hat{\mathcal A}$, which shows that $A_0 \in \sigma(X)$. In conclusion $\mathfrak B(X)\subseteq \sigma(X)$, and since the opposite inclusion always holds this means that
$$\mathfrak B(X) = \sigma(X),$$ and so the condition is sufficient.

---

COMMENTS on examples and partial results I explored

A few examples I considered helped me to successively weaken the sufficient condition $\hat{\mathcal A}=\mathcal P(\hat \Omega)$.

1) It is easy to see that this it not necessary, since if you have any probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$ with $\mathcal A \subsetneq \mathcal P(\Omega)$ and a measurable space $(\hat\Omega,\hat{\mathcal A})$ with $\hat\Omega=\Omega$ and $\hat{\mathcal{A}}=\mathcal A$, then defining $X\colon\Omega\to\hat\Omega$ as the identity (well defined, since domain and codomain actually are the same—or we could just call it the 'inclusion map'—) gives $\sigma(X)=\mathcal A$ and since any event $A\in \mathcal A$ is also one of the elements of $\hat{\mathcal A}$ and also $X^{-1}(A)=A$, $\sigma(X)=\mathfrak B(X)$ trivially.

I considered then an example that suggested a weaker sufficient condition.

2) Let's take $\Omega=\hat\Omega=\{0,1\}$, $\hat{\mathcal A}=\mathcal P(\Omega)$, $P$ can be any probability (the general case would be $P(\{1\})=p$, $P(\{0\})=q$, with $p,q\in [0,1]$ and $p+q=1$—and of course $P(\emptyset)=0$ and $P(\Omega)=1$—), and take $\hat{\mathcal A}=\{\emptyset,\{0,1\}\}$, which is trivially a $\sigma$-algebra over $\hat\Omega$. It is immediate to check that $\sigma(X)=\{\emptyset,\{0,1\}\}\subsetneq\Omega$ but $\mathfrak B(X)=\Omega$.

One might think that the problem here is that, again, $\hat{A}$ was taken strictly smaller than $\mathcal P (\Omega)$, but the simple structure of the example let us see that the problem is that it was too small relative to $\mathcal A$. The same would have happened for a larger $\Omega$ maybe infinite, even uncountable, say $\mathbb R$, and $\mathcal A$ none of the trivial or the discrete $\sigma$-algebras, say $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. If we take $\hat {\mathcal A}=\{\emptyset,\mathbb R\}$, or any $\sigma$-algebra smaller than the set of borelians, then the same situation will arise.

3) In general, the 'problem' in the previous example seemed to be the existence of sets $A\in \mathcal A$ such that $X(A)$ is not a member of $\hat {\mathcal A}$.

This gives a (weaker) sufficient condition:

> $$X(A)\subseteq \hat{\mathcal A},\quad \forall A \in \mathcal A.$$

This can be proved by taking $A_0\in\mathcal B(X)$, that is, $A_0 \in \mathcal A$ and there exists $\hat A_0 \in \hat{\Omega}$ such that $A_0=X^{-1}(\hat A_0)$.

But this implies $X(A_0)=X\big(X^{-1}(\hat A_0)\big)=\hat A_0$, and since by hypothesis $X(A_0)\in \hat{\mathcal A}$, in fact $\hat A_0\in \hat{\mathcal A}$. Then, $A_0=X^{-1}(\hat A_0) \in \sigma(X)$, as we wanted to prove.

4) At first it seemed intuitive to me that this would also be a necessary condition, but I got stucked while looking for a proof (which of course did not exist).

I quickly reasoned that if there is $A_0\in \mathcal A$ such that $X(A_0)\notin \hat{\mathcal A}$, then **$A_1=X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big) \in B(X)$** but since $A_1=X^{-1}(\hat A_1)$ implies $\hat A_1= X(A_0) \notin \hat{\mathcal A}$, then $A_1$ **is in $\mathfrak B(X)$ but not in $\sigma(X)$.

That would be great... if it wasn't completely wrong. Of course $X(A_0)\subset \hat\Omega$, but too conclude $A_1\in\mathfrak(X)$ we should also check that $A_1 \in \mathcal A$. And guess what: no, I couldn't. (Just in case: $X^{-1}\big(X(A)) \supset A$, but equality need not hold—yet it could hold in particular cases, as for injective $X$).

Not being able to prove that important detail, I started looking for an example where this exact situation arose.

5) This put me to consider more interesting examples involving more complex $\sigma$-algebras. I avoided borelian sets for there's no simple general expression to work with them (of course, you can use a characterization involving ordinal numbers and think of sets of class $G_{\delta\sigma\delta}$ or $F_{\sigma\delta\sigma\delta\ldots}$ or worst... but I said 'simple'). So I relied on the $\sigma$-algebras of countable sets and their complements for a less finitistic example.

Consider now the probability space $\big([0,1],\hat{\mathcal A},P\big)$, with
$$\hat{\mathcal A}=\{A\subset [0,1]\colon A \text{ is countable or } [0,1]\setminus A \text{ is countable}\}$$
and any possible $P$ (Borel measure, for instance), and have the measure space $\big([0,1],\hat{\mathcal A}\big)$ where
$$\hat{\mathcal A}= \big\{\emptyset,\{0\},(0,1],[0,1]\big\}.$$

I considered several r.v. until some thoughts about uncountability of the preimages of elements in $\hat{\mathcal A}$ and also of their complements led me to consider $X\colon [0,1]\to [0,1]$ as the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Before going further, some additional words on the Cantor function. For the sake of brevity let's just remember that if $X$ is the Cantor function, then:

- $X$ is a non-decreasing continuous function from $[0,1]$ onto itself with $X(0)=0$, $X(1)=1$, $X\big((0,1)\big)$; this implies

-- $X\big([0,1]\big)=[0,1]$ ($X$ is surjective),
-- $X^{-1}\big(\{0\}\big)=\{0\}\in\hat{\mathcal A}$ and $X^{-1}\big((0,1]\big)=(0,1]$, and so $X$ is measurable;

- if $\upsilon\in(0,1)$ has finite binary development (equivalently, if it can  be expressed as a dyadic function), then $X^{-1}(\upsilon)$ is a non-degenerate closed interval, say $[a,b]$ with $a<b$; it can also be seen that $[a,b]\cap \mathcal C=\{a,b\};$
- otherwise $X^{-1}(\upsilon)$ is a singleton, and it's only element belongs to $\mathcal C$;
- if $D$ is the (countable) set of all dyadic fractions in $(0,1)$, then $[0,1]\setminus X^{-1}(D)=X^{-1}\big([0,1]\setminus D\big)$ is uncountable (since so is $[0,1]\setminus D$).

While constructing and analyzing this example the main goal of doing so was not well defined and actually changed frequently, but in a sense I wanted a more complex case without the property mentioned in where I tried to see if $\sigma(X)=\mathfrak B(X)$ too, or not. My intuition was that $\hat{\mathcal A}$ is too small, since there are plenty of sets $A\in \mathcal A$ for which $X(A)\notin \hat{\mathcal A}$. Basically, all the uncountably many events $A$ but $\{0\}$, $(0,1]$ and of course $\emptyset$ and $[0,1]$ have their image outside $\hat{\mathcal A}$. But counterexamples were not obvious...

Suppose $A_0=X^{-1}(\hat A_0)$, where $\hat A_0$ is a subset of $\hat \Omega\setminus \hat{\mathcal A}$. We want to find such an $A_0$ which belongs to $\mathcal A$, since this would be the element of $\mathfrak B(X)$ which won't be in $\sigma(X)$.

I worked out some special cases ($\mathcal C$ stands for the Cantor set):

- If $\hat A_0 \subset [0,1]\setminus D$, then $X^{-1}(\hat A)\subsetneq \mathcal C$ is uncountable (as explained above) and its complement contains (properly, in fact) $[0,1]\setminus \mathcal C$, also uncountable. Then, $X^{-1}(\hat A_0)\notin \mathcal A$ and does not belong to $\mathfrak B(X)$ (nor $\sigma(X)$.
- It is an immediate consequence that $X^{-1}(\hat A_0)$ does not belong to $\mathcal A$ either, if $\hat A_0$ were contained in $D$.
- The first case suggested me another case to consider. Let us call $\mathcal C_u$ to the (proper) part of $\mathcal C$ given by $X^{-1}\big([0,1]\big)$, and $\mathcal C_c$ to its complement, which is a countable set ($c$ and $u$ stand for 'countable' and 'uncountable', in fact.) If we choose $A_0 \subset \mathcal C_c$, which is in $\mathcal A$ (unless $A_0=\{0\}$), we get $\hat A_0=X(A_0)\notin \hat{\mathcal A}$. This breaks the condition in 3) that I had thought at some point that would be necessary. But this provided me with no counterexample for $\mathfrak B(X)=\sigma(X)$, because once again $X^{-1}(\hat A_0)=X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)$ does not belong to $\mathcal A$ (because it contains an interval and it's complement contains $\mathcal C_u$). So, again, we haven't found an element of $\mathfrak B(X)$.

All this made me considere the schema
$$A_0 \in \mathcal A \colon \quad A_1=X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)$$

In order to find counterexamples we had to discard those cases in which:

- $X(A_0)\in \hat{\mathcal A}$, since then $A_1 \in \sigma(X)$;
- $A_1 \notin \mathcal A$: those are not in $\mathfrak B(X)$ (nor in $\sigma(X)$, of course).

What this said is that the sufficient condition $X(A)\in \hat{\mathcal A}$ only becomes relevant for those $A\in \mathcal A$ such that $X^{-1}\big(X(A)\big)\in \mathcal A$ too. Or, in other words, that whenever we have $A\in \mathcal A$ and $X(A) \notin \hat{\mathcal A}$ we need $X^{-1}\big(X(A)\big)\notin \mathcal A$ in order to avoid a counterexample to $\mathfrak B(X) = \sigma(X)$.

This conclusion actually allowed me to arrange a counterexample:
- If $A_0$ is a countable nonempty subset of $\mathcal C_u$ (and is not exactly $\{0\}$, the injectivity of $X$ over $\mathcal C_u$ implies that while $A_0 \in \mathcal A$, again $X(A_0)\notin \hat{\mathcal A}$; but this time this becomes relevant because $X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big) \in \mathcal A$, too (in fact this is the same as $A_0$).

A general argument in the same spirit gave the proof of necessity that appears in the first part.

I've also seen that considering sets $A$ which were not in $\mathcal A$ did not strengthen this necessary condition since every time we find $A_0\notin \mathcal A$ for which $X(A_0)\notin \hat{\mathcal A}$ but $X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)\in \mathcal A$, we would be able to also take $A_1=X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)\in \mathcal A$, and this would give a counterexample: indeed, $$X(A_1)=X\Big(X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)\Big)=X(A_0) \notin \hat{\mathcal A}$$
and
$$X^{-1}\big(X(A_1)\big)=X^{-1}\bigg(X\Big(X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big)\Big)\bigg)=X^{-1}\big(X(A_0)\big) \in \hat{\mathcal A},$$
Then, $A_1$ is also a counterexample, but with $A_1$ being an event (unlike $A_0$).

Of course, all this took many steps forward and backwards. I finally crossed my fingers for this new condition to be also sufficient, and luck did its part.

Comment: Very nice work. From your condition, it follows immediately (for example), that if $(\hat{\Omega},\hat{\mathcal{A}}) = (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ and $X(\Omega)$ is countable, then $\sigma(X) = \mathfrak{B}(X)$. I wonder if equality also holds in this example if $X(\Omega)$ is uncountable.

Comment: Also, your intellectual problem-solving-pathway is very engaging to read!

Comment: Glad you enjoy it! Still thinking on your previous comment... Quite interesting and stimulating questions BTW.

Comment: I kinda felt it couldn't hold in general for uncountable $X(\Omega)$. To go for an easy counterexample we don't have $\hat{\mathcal A}=\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, but remember that if $X$ is injective $$X^{-1}\big(X(A)\big)=A$$ and so the condition 
$$A\in \mathcal A \implies X(A) \in \hat{\mathcal A}$$ becomes also necesary.
So I was looking for a counterexample, and for simplicity we can take $\Omega=\mathbb R$ o $\Omega=[0,1]$, and $X$ the identity or the inclusion.

But to make it fail, we need larger $\sigma$-algebra than Borel...

Comment: ... Of course there are larger ones, but not on all of them it is possible to give a finite measure. But $\big([0,1],\mathcal L, \lambda\big)$ (Lebesgue measurable sets with Lebesgue measure). Since there are subsets which are Lebesgue but not Borel measurable, and for those $A$ we have $A\in \mathcal L$ but not in $\mathcal B(X)$. Such an $A$ belongs to $\mathcal B(X)$ but not to $\sigma (X)$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. This is indeed a counterexample! Thanks for the effort; all of this greatly improves my intuitive understanding of the information contained in $\sigma(X)$.

Comment: It helped me a lot, too. I had asked myself these questions in one way or another before, but I hadn't given it much attention until you clearly stated this. It's always a two way street with math.

Comment: I have just realized that against all my efforts I mixed up "borelians" and "possible properties in the previous comment! lol

Comment: Of course, I meant: "... and for those $A$ we have $A\in \mathcal L$ but $A\notin \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Such an $A$ belongs to $\mathfrak B(X)$ but not to $\sigma(X)$." =D